# Setting the admin theme only inside the overlay

Tags: 7

On my site, I have the Overlay module enabled, and I have selected an admin theme that is different from the theme used as default.
Sometimes, a page for which the admin theme is set is accessed with a direct link, and the admin theme is used. I would like to show the page with the default theme, and use the admin theme only with the overlay.

Is there a way to achieve this (module, or code to use in a custom module)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Overlay Theme](http://drupal.org/project/overlay_theme) module would probably be ideal:

> Overlay theme is a small module that provides an option to set the theme of modal frames provided by the core Overlay module, different from the default which is the Administration theme.

Using that you could set your default admin theme to the same as the front end, and set the overlay theme to what ever you like.

Comment: It seems I forgot to accept this answer. I don't know who down-voted, but the suggested module is the one I am using.